# What is the appropriate method for transporting a Torah scroll?

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, vehicles-transportation

Is there a best practice for transporting a Torah scroll from one building, or one city, to another?

Answer (score 2):

There is alot on this topic. Some say 10 people should accompany the Torah. Also it is customary to cover it with a tallis. The Torah should not pass by dirty areas. For more of a comprehensive idea see [here](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue20.pdf).

Comment: @Michael: This would be a better answer if you summarized the main pints in the article you linked.

Comment: If you get around to summarizing the main points of the article you linked (about moving a Sefer Torah) I'll upvote your post.

Answer (score 0):

I would summarize the procedure as "treat the Sefer Torah with honour". At least two people accompanying the Sefer, covered as as far as possible, don't go anywhere dirty or unpleasant. I had to take a Sefer for correction when I was a student. There were two of us, we took the train and then a taxi (students didn't have cars then). Obviously if it is raining there is the need to protect the Sefer from damage as well. A large plastic bag would come in handy but then there should be another cover (cloth, tallit etc.) as an honourable covering.

Comment: Can you source any of this answer?

Comment: @msh210 No. This is personal experience while at university with no Rav to ask directly and a need to get the community's Sefer Torah to a Sofer Sta"m ASAP.

Comment: @Epicentre: What about covering it with a tallis?

Comment: @BruceJames Not necessarily appropriate for a long journey outside Israel, but certainly can be used.